# how to get last time from sqlite in android for sync

Tags: android, server, synchronization

i am trying to develop mobile app so, this time  i want to sync with sqlite to remote MySQL database. to pass last sync time from mobile to server another sync tha's my logic

Comment: Best way is you store last sync time in shared preference.

Comment: You can either store the last sync time in shared preference or in the SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

instead of using `last sync time` create one table which maintains the `db_version` of server or use `shared preference`.

whenever you want to `sync` you can simply pass the `db_version` and if server will send you updated database.